# select all row values as a list

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I have a table `tasks` that looks like this:

```
userId          caption    status       id
1               Paul       done         1
2               Ali        notDone      18
3               Kevin      notDone      12
3               Elisa      notDone      13
```

I join it with another table `users` to find the number of `tasks`where `status = notDone`. I do it like this:

```
    SELECT u.id, 
       t.number_of_tasks,
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT userId, COUNT(*) number_of_tasks
      FROM tasks 
      WHERE status = "notDone"
      GROUP BY userId
      ) t ON u.id = t.userId
    """
```

Now, I want create another column `captions` that somehow includes a list of all `captions` that were included in the `count`and fulfil the join + where conditions.

For example, I would expect this as one of the rows. How can I achieve this?

```
userId      number_of_tasks     captions
3           2                   ["Kevin", "Elisa"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_group_array()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jgrouparray) aggregate function inside the subquery to create the list of captions for each user:

```
SELECT u.id, t.number_of_tasks, t.captions
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT userId, 
         COUNT(*) number_of_tasks,
         json_group_array(caption) captions
  FROM tasks 
  WHERE status = 'notDone'
  GROUP BY userId
) t ON u.id = t.userId;
```

Comment: but int this case, when I load the column/row in python, it would be a string instead of a list. is there any way for it to be a proper list that I can index

Comment: @x89 SQLite does not support lists. If you want to access the value of the column `captions` as a list you can do it with Python code (maybe with the method split()).